# Can't create a new domain in Ampps 3.9

Tags: localserver, ampps

I start heading on the [ampps](http://localhost/ampps/index.php?act=ampps_domainadd) page to add a new domain for my project which has his location in another partition.

I successfully enter and fill the form on the add_domain's page but when I submit. I unfortunately and always get an error like this :

[image]

The unexpected thing is that the domain which is providing an error has seen to be saved on the [manage_domain](http://localhost/ampps/index.php?act=ampps_domainmanage)'s page just like on the following picture :

[image]

I'm getting an "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" when I try accessing my project with the so-called new domain's.

.

Please, if anyone has an idea to get rid of this matter. I will be very grateful to (him/her)!
Sorry for my bad writing and happy "pre-new year" Everyone  (:b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if working for you, but I manually added my own domain name into hosts, and after i created the domain, and unchecked `add an entry`, still give me that error, but when i click on list domains, appears my domain, then i restart ampps and close all browsers, and that works good.

Answer (score 0):

open  'Command Prompt' Run as admin

```
> echo 127.0.0.1 your_domain >> C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
> sc stop AMPPS_Apache
> sc start AMPPS_Apache
```

Now you can browse your web.